# YOLO v1 - what is the prediction data format and where is it specified?

Tags: yolo

[Yolo v1 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02640) says the prediction is encoded as `(B*5+C)` where `B` is the number of bounding boxes, `5` is the size of a bounding box prediction `(c, x, y, h, w)`, and `C` is the number of classes. B is 2 and C is 20.

Hence it gives an impression that the prediction data is stored in an array in the same order `[P, P, C]` where `P` is a bounding box prediction `(c, x, y, w, h)`.

[image]

However, the implementation code such as [YOLOv1 from Scratch](https://youtu.be/n9_XyCGr-MI?list=PLhhyoLH6Ijfw0TpCTVTNk42NN08H6UvNq&t=413) shows the prediction data format is `[C, P, P]`.

[image]

If I need to take the first `(c, x, y, w, h)` prediction, should I take the first 5 float32 values from a prediction?

```
cxywh: np.ndarray = prediction[:5]
```

Or should I skip the first 20 values?

```
cxywh: np.ndarray = prediction[21:26]
```

Is there is a document or resource that specifies the format of the YOLO v1 prediction data, please point out.

Comment: there are various implementations and it's okay the format if you handle the loss function accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @yakhyo, so depending on the implementation, it can be B*(c, x, y, w, h)+C or C+B*(c, x, y, w, h), and just need to be aware which?

Comment: According to the implementation [code](https://github.com/aladdinpersson/Machine-Learning-Collection/blob/master/ML/Pytorch/object_detection/YOLO/loss.py#L39)  `box1 = predictions[..., 21:25]`  and `box2 = predictions[..., 26:30]`  so the format is `C+B*5`